# Changing along a tensor field, the Lie Derivative

Tags: derivatives, tensors

I can find considerable information about how to use the Lie Derivative to measure the change of a tensor field along a vector field, but I can't seem to find anything for the converse.  What if I want to do what the Lie Derivative does, except I don't want to act *on* a tensor field, I want a Lie Derivative that acts *with* it, on say, a vector field.  Does such an operation exist?

Thanks,